# Incrementing char pointer inside C struct

Tags: c, pointers, c-strings

For a char variable in C, you can normally increment through char pointers like so (this example just gets rid of spaces in a string):

```
void remove_spaces(char *str)
{
    const char *ptr = str;

    do
    {
        while (*ptr == ' ')
        {
            ++ptr;
        }
    } while (*str++ = *ptr++);
}

int main()
{
    char string[20];
    strcpy(string, "foo bar");
    remove_spaces(string);
}
```

In the case that you pass a struct like this one:

```
struct line
{
    char string[20];
    char something_else[20]
};

void remove_spaces(struct line *str)
{
    const char *ptr = str->string;

    do
    {
        while (*ptr == ' ')
        {
            ++ptr;
        }
    } while (str->string++ = *ptr++); // incorrect syntax
}

int main()
{
    struct line str;

    strcpy(str.string, "foo bar");
    remove_spaces(&str);
}
```

What is the correct syntax to increment this line in the while loop:

```
while (str->string++ = *ptr++);
```

(Note: I need to pass the whole struct to the function as there will be other operations with other members of the struct as well)

Comment: Keep `remove_spaces` as in the first example - it's a good name for a well-defined task. If you need another function to do that and other stuff to that struct, call `remove_spaces` from that other function.

Comment: What is the reason you want two strings instead of two pointers advancing though the same string? If you want to preserve the original, make a copy before calling your original remove spaces on the copy.

Comment: It's a massive struct with a lot of string parsing, the function was just to serve as an example off the top of my head, just wanted to see the syntax to advance a struct pointer to a char. Note the "Note:"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a second pointer:

```
void remove_spaces(struct line *str)
{
    const char *ptr = str->string;
    char *ptr2 = str->string;

    do
    {
        while (*ptr == ' ')
        {
            ++ptr;
        }
    } while (ptr2++ = *ptr++); // incorrect syntax
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to directly increment the struct pointer or is it impossible?

Comment: You can only increment a variable (an lvalue), not an rvalue.  In your original code, you're trying to increment an array, which is implicitly converted to an rvalue pointer, so there's no variable to increment.

Answer (score 2):

A string in a struct is a string. You don't need to invent any special treatment for the latter. You already know how to deal with a string. Keep your original `remove_spaces` function, and forget the second variant altogether.

```
remove_spaces(str.string);
```

That's all.

Comment: It's being used in a massive function with a huge struct and multiple operations on the struct members. I tried to produce a minimal example off the top of my head to use the struct pointer. I know I could simply just pass the char, but because the struct has so many members the function would have to look like void function(str.thing, str.thing2, str.thing3, str.thing4, etc.)

Comment: @Mick Same thing. Write a function that calls `remove_spaces` for each of the fields.

Comment: It's a part of a massive parsing function where there is a main string, then each of the struct members point to a specific point in the string. The real function has nothing to do with removing spaces, and the logic for finding the correct part in the string to point to is different for almost all struct members. The function is also called close to a million times in some cases, so traversing the string for each separate struct member is out of the question. The function is meant to do one pass through and do multiple operations for performance.

Comment: @Mick Your question and your last comment seem to refer to wildly different problems. If you have a problem with many pointers that point into the same string, you may want to ask a question about that.